# Python look for variable in JSON

Tags: python, json

I'm expecting a JSON msg to be parsed with Python along these lines to come in through MQTT:

```
{"OPTION1": "0", "OPTION2": "50", "OPTION3": "0", "OPTION4": "0"}
```

Depending on the circumstances, these options may or may not be parsed through Python into the JSON msg, and as such, it may end up looking as:

```
{"OPTION1": "0", "OPTION3": "0", "OPTION4": "0"}
```

And thus skipping OPTION2 and it's value entirely.

To avoid my script borking out on my, I was thinking of scanning if the option is there first, before setting it, like so:

```
        if data['OPTION1']:
                >do something here<
        else:
               continue
```

However, this doesn't seem to work, it comes up with:

```
  File "listen-mqtt.py", line 28
    continue
SyntaxError: 'continue' not properly in loop
```

Any help would be really appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: `pass` is what you looking for (not `continue`)

Comment: `else` clause is unnecessary. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html?highlight=continue

Answer (score 2):

If you are working with if else **pass**, **continue** is used with loops:-

```
 if data['OPTION1']:
     >do something here<
 else:
     pass
```

Continue is used with loops. Also you can try:-

```
for dataItem in data:
   if "OPTION2" == dataItem:
      pass
   else:
     >do something< 


for dataItem in data:
   if "OPTION2" == dataItem:
      continue
   >do something<
```

Answer (score 0):

`continue` is used with loops, you might need `pass`ehere. Also, you can use `in` to check if a key is available in a dictionary:

```
if 'OPTION1' in data:
  # do something
else:
  pass
```

**But I don't think, that is what you want!** You want to have your default values and fill in the blanks if the key is not available in `data`:

```
defaults = {"OPTION1": "0", "OPTION2": "50", "OPTION3": "0", "OPTION4": "0"}
finalData = defaults.update(data)
```

Find out more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26853961/2295964).

Comment: Your first option seems to give me a syntax error:     else:
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: yes because instead of `#` you have to have some statements. Replace it for test purposes with `pass` and the error is gone.

Comment: I have added my statement in between the if and the else. I did not take your code example literally.

Comment: I just loaded your example data with `json.loads` and ran the abovementioned code. No syntax error, whatsoever. Which part isn't working for you?

Comment: I too have added my example with:         data = json.loads(msg.payload), I have then used your if 'OPTION1' in data: *my statement* else: pass but it still gives me a syntax error on else: - i have no idea why.

Comment: I cannot possibly say why and which syntax error you're getting. to verify, you can just write e.g. `'OPTION2' in data` in your python console and see the results. However, I still think the second solution (with `update`) is what you should use *if* you only want to update default values.